# Convert Json string literals to utf8 characters with perl or bash

Tags: regex, perl, printf

I have a file full of \u codes and want to replace them all with corresponding utf8 character, for example "\u00FC" will become "ü":

Here is how far I got:

```
echo 'f\u00FCr' | perl -C -p -e "s/\\\\(u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/ chr(hex(sprintf('0x%s', '00FC'))) /ge"
```

This will output the expected "für". I just can't figure out how to use the value of the capture group into the sprintf function? $1, $1, \1 and \1 are not working. Guess it will be something very simple, but don't know what to search for. :-)

Or if there is a better approach for this, please let me know, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is correct, although you are mistakenly including the `u` in the capture.

But you have to be careful about escaping for the shell. You are apparently using `sh` or similar (based on your need to escape the `\`), so you have to escape certain characters when using double-quotes. That includes `$`. Your shell is interpolating `$1` before `perl` sees it. Best to use single-quotes.

```sh
perl -C -pe's/\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/ chr(hex($1)) /ge'
```

---

Note that `sprintf('0x%s', '00FC')` is equivalent to `'0x' . '00FC'`, but `hex` doesn't require the leading `0x`. `'00FC'` (and thus `$1`) is sufficient.

Comment: This was driving me insane, thank you very much!! Good catch with the "u", too .. if someone needs it with double quotes, you need to escape the backslash and the dollar: `perl -C -pe "s/\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/ chr(hex(\$1)) /ge"`

Comment: I strongly recommend against that. It's just too error-prone

Comment: huh, why is that?

Comment: Your question is proof that's it's super easy to forget to escape something. Why take the risk and effort, only to end up with something less readable?

Comment: Fair enough. In my question i have the single quotes already inside, so i like using another type of quotes outside. Think there was some language I used long ago where you could not escape the single quotes, no idea. Or when you inject variables from the outer bash script, but I just read there are better ways. Thanks for the help and the extra hints!

Comment: Most single quotes can be avoided. One can use `""`, or `q{}` for string literals. Inside double-quote string literals, one can use `\x27`. And you can effectively escape them by using `'\''` or `'"'"'`.

Comment: Re "*Or when you inject variables from the outer bash script*", Don't do this. This is horrible. Writing Perl code from the shell is extremely hard. Contrary to what you claim, this is a reason *not* to use double-quotes.